# Dplyr group_by summarize keep min/max value for each column within group, depending on column suffix

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe containing groups that I want to collapse into single entries in such a way that the values of the new rows are either the minimum or maximum values within each group, depending on the column name.

For example, given:

```r
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(grp = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B'), 
                  v1_high = rnorm(4), 
                  v2_high = rnorm(4), 
                  v3_low = rnorm(4))
```

```
# original
   grp    v1_high    v2_high     v3_low
 1   A -0.6264538  0.3295078  0.5757814
 2   A  0.1836433 -0.8204684 -0.3053884
 3   B -0.8356286  0.4874291  1.5117812
 4   B  1.5952808  0.7383247  0.3898432
```

I would like to generate a new dataframe with two entries corresponding to the groups "A" and "B" with the maximum values of each column ending in `_high` and the minimum values of each column ending in `_low`.

In this case:

```
# desired result
  grp   v1_high   v2_high     v3_low
1   A 0.1836433 0.3295078 -0.3053884
2   B 1.5952808 0.7383247  0.3898432
```

Finally, the number and names of such columns are not known beforehand.

Ideally, the summarization would also handle the case where there are no `_min` columns present, and only `_max` ones, although I can always check for this scenario manually and handle the two cases in separately using an `if () { .. }` statement.

Any suggestions? It seems like this should be possible using the [summarize_at()](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise_all.html) function, but I haven't figured out how to apply different functions to different sets of columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to group by 'grp', get the `max` of columns that end with 'high' (column names), use that also as grouping column and get the `min` of columns that end with 'low'

```
library(dplyr)    
dat %>%
   group_by(grp) %>%  
   mutate_at(vars(ends_with('high')), max) %>% 
   group_by_at(vars(ends_with('high')), .add = TRUE) %>% 
   summarise_at(vars(ends_with('low')), min)
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   grp, v1_high [2]
#  grp   v1_high v2_high v3_low
#  <fct>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 A       0.184   0.330 -0.305
#2 B       1.60    0.738  0.390
```

---

It would also work if there are no `min` columns

```
dat[-4] %>%
    group_by(grp) %>%  
    mutate_at(vars(ends_with('high')), max) %>% 
    group_by_at(vars(ends_with('high')), .add = TRUE) %>%   
    summarise_at(vars(ends_with('low')), min)
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   grp, v1_high [2]
#  grp   v1_high v2_high
#  <fct>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#1 A       0.184   0.330
#2 B       1.60    0.738
```

---

Or another option is `map2`

```
library(purrr)
map2(list(min, max), list('low', 'high'), ~ 
      dat %>% 
         select(grp, ends_with(.y)) %>%
         group_by(grp) %>%
         summarise_all(.x)) %>% 
         reduce(inner_join, by = 'grp')
```

Comment: @KeithHughitt  Thank you for the response.  I also added a `map2` based solution in case you want to generalize with more functions