# Condensing a data frame in R but retaining min/max values

Tags: r, tidyverse, survival-analysis

I'm formatting data for proportional hazards survival analysis (based on wildlife telemetry data), and have interval steps for data. I'm hoping to combine these time steps, and only start a new row when an animal goes missing for 1+ time steps.

```
# Current data
   id    start end  fail cause   
 1 1       2     3     0 NA      
 2 1       3     4     0 NA      
 3 1       4     5     0 NA      
 4 1       5     6     0 NA      
 5 1       6     7     0 NA      
 6 1       7     8     0 NA      
 7 1       8     9     0 NA   
 8 1      12    13     0 NA      
 9 1      13    14     0 NA      
10 1      14    15     0 NA      
11 1      15    16     0 NA      
12 1      16    17     0 NA      
13 1      17    18     0 NA      
14 1      18    19     0 NA      
15 1      19    20     0 NA   
16 1      23    24     0 NA      
17 1      24    25     0 Censored
18 2       2     3     0 NA      
19 2       3     4     0 NA      
20 2       4     5     0 NA      
21 2       5     6     0 NA      
22 2       6     7     0 Censored
23 3       2     3     0 NA      
24 3       3     4     0 NA    
25 3       8     9     1 Dead
```

I am hoping to get something like this:

```
# What I would like it to look like
   id    start end  fail cause   
 1 1       2     9     0 Censored            
 2 1      12    20     0 Censored         
 3 1      23    25     0 Censored      
 4 2       2     7     0 Censored      
 5 3       2     4     0 Censored      
 6 3       8     9     1 Dead
```

I've been doing some searches, and am thinking something like this might work, if I can somehow create a unique identified for for each period of consecutive monitoring (linked to the animal ID):

```
library(dplyr)    
dat %>%
   group_by(grp) %>%  
   mutate_at(vars(ends_with('high')), max) %>% 
   group_by_at(vars(ends_with('high')), .add = TRUE) %>% 
   summarise_at(vars(ends_with('low')), min)
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   grp, v1_high [2]
#  grp   v1_high v2_high v3_low
#  <fct>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 A       0.184   0.330 -0.305
#2 B       1.60    0.738  0.390
```

(copied from one of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56584088/dplyr-group-by-summarize-keep-min-max-value-for-each-column-within-group-depend))

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure how you want to handle fail/cause, but one way to do this is

```
dat %>%
  group_by(id, gap=cumsum(start - lag(end, default = first(start))>1)) %>% 
  summarize(start=first(start), end=last(end), 
            fail=last(fail), cause=coalesce(last(cause),"Censored")) %>% 
  select(-gap)
#      id start   end  fail cause   
#   <int> <int> <int> <int> <chr>   
# 1     1     2     9     0 Censored
# 2     1    12    20     0 Censored
# 3     1    23    25     0 Censored
# 4     2     2     7     0 Censored
# 5     3     2     4     0 Censored
# 6     3     8     9     1 Dead
```

This works by creating a "gap" variable that increments each time the difference between start and the previous last is more than 1.

Comment: This worked perfectly, it does exactly what I need it to do with differences in censored/dead!